# Use VB.NET DLL in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

I would like to use a Class Library project in a Windows Forms project. Here's what I did:

- Make a Class Library project.
- Code it.
- Go to BUILD on the menu bar, then do Build.

Now that I've done that, I don't see an option to use the DLL in my other project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the library project to use it.

In the project where you want to use the library, right click on the "References" node in the solution explorer, and select "Add Reference...".

It will open the reference manager, there you select the "Solution" tab. It will show you the projects in your solution, and you can check the checkbox in front of your library project.

Comment: What if it isn't in the same solution?

Comment: @snuggles08: Then you can either add the project to that solution, copy the DLL file to the `bin` folder, or leave the DLL file where it is (all depending on how you want the dependancy on the library). To add a reference to a DLL file instead of a project, select the `Browse` tag in the reference manager, and locate the file.

Answer (score 0):

In your "other" project "right click" References => "Add Reference...." => "Browse..."

Then navigate to your dll and select it.